# shell: map columns of a TSV file using a separately defined mapping

Tags: scripting, csv

Suppose I have the following tab-separated file `data.tsv`:

```
1 a 3
2 b 2
3 a 10
2 c 2
2 a 8
```

Now, I want to exchange the values in column 1 - say, turn them from IDs to names - by using the following `map.tsv`:

```
1 foo
2 bar
3 baz
```

The result should be:

```
foo a 3
bar b 2
baz a 10
bar c 2
bar a 8
```

I know that for **one** map it is possible with some AWK tricks, but I would like to be able to use multiple mappings for multiple columns and have a simple call like this:

```
$ my_map_command 1:map.tsv < data.tsv
```

Is there a command that does something similar?

Comment: what is the problem with `awk 'FNR==NR{map[$1]=$2}FNR!=NR{print map[$1],$2,$3}' map.tsv data.tsv` ? It won't get simpler I guess. Make this a short script, so you can easily run it.

Comment: There might be some tool in csvkit

Comment: @pLumo The problem is that the trick with `FNR==NR` only works once - I cannot use multiple maps simultaneously. I guess it would be possible by piping the result to a next call, but that's not very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in a file called `my_map_command`:

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
FNR==NR{map[$1]=$2}
FNR!=NR{
    printf "%s%s",map[$1],OFS
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s",$i,OFS
    printf "\n"
}
```

Then run:

```
chmod u+x my_map_command
```

Call your script like:

```
./my_map_command map.tsv data.tsv
```

Multiple map files:

```bsh
./my_map_command <(cat map1.tsv map2.tsv) data.tsv
```

Comment: Is there a way to supply the index of the mapped column (`1` in this case) as a parameter to the script?

Comment: sure. Add `-v variable=value`, then you can use `variable` inside the script. Only some small changes needed in the script, but I'll leave that as a task for you.

Answer (score 2):

## csvkit

The command `csvjoin` from the package [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can be used to achieve similar behaviour:

```
$ csvjoin -tH -c 1,1 data.tsv map.tsv 2> /dev/null
a,b,c,b2
1,a,3,foo
2,b,2,bar
3,a,10,baz
2,c,2,bar
2,a,8,bar
```

Reordering/removing columns is trivial and can be done with `csvcut` from the same package.

## coreutils

The standard `join(1)`can be used too, but it requires sorting the data (and the map if it's not sorted):

```
$ join -j1 -t '       ' <(sort -k1 data.tsv) map.tsv
1       a       3       foo
2       a       8       bar
2       b       2       bar
2       c       2       bar
3       a       10      baz
```

Both cases can do only one mapping at a time, so piping to a further call is required for multiple mappings.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a variable between the file arguments:

```
awk '!data{map[$1]=$2; next} $1 in map{$1=map[$1]} 1' map1 map2... data=1 data
```

- read values into `map` array until a flag is given
- after flag value is given (`data=1` argument), swap field in data for mapped value

---

```
awk '
!data {
    map[field,$1]=$2
    maps[field]
    next
}
{
    for (i in maps)
        if ((i,$i) in map)
            $i=map[i,$i]
}
1' field=1 map1 field=2 map2 data=1 data
```

- field 1 in `data` is mapped to value from `map1`
- field 2 in `data` is mapped to value from `map2`

Answer (score 0):

Or just use a language you might already know for interrogating tabular data: [sql](/questions/tagged/sql);

Syntax is easy: `q "<SQL Query>"`, or `q -t "…"` if your files are tsv, or `-d …` for other delimiters. Your query would be:

```sql
SELECT m.c2, d.c2, d.c3 
FROM data.tsv AS d INNER JOIN map.tsv AS m
                   ON d.c1==m.c1
```

[`q - text as data`](http://harelba.github.io/q/)([packaged](https://packages.debian.org/buster/q-text-as-data) [everywhere](https://pkgs.org/download/q-text-as-data)) is a neat tool to apply the power of [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) to any tabular, delimited data. Even STDIN works, just specify "-" instead as filename, think `JOIN - as m` to replace map.tsv with something you pipe in.

Nice "bonus" of `q`:  You can use SQL `ORDER`, `GROUP`, as well as do calculations! Showing it all off:

```bsh
q 'SELECT m.c2 AS I, d.c2, d.c3, ROUND(d.c3*0.4, 2) as b
   FROM data.tsv AS d INNER JOIN - AS m
                      ON d.c1==m.c1
   ORDER BY I' < map.tsv

bar b 2 0.8
bar c 2 0.8
⋮
```

Note: The name "q" is totally ungooglable, so add "text-as-data" or "harelba"(the author) when searching.